# Yii: adding an attribute to model

Tags: forms, yii

I'm trying to add an attribute to one of my model ("CustomUser") which inherits of my model "User".

I want to use this attribute in the form "createUser" as a validation password field. I want to use a virtual attribute because I can't modify my DB which has only one field "password".

But then, when I try to get the view which contains the form, this error is displayed:

> Property "User.password_verification" is not defined.

and this is the lines where the error occurs:

```
echo $form->labelEx($user,'password_verification');    
echo $form->textField($user,'password_verification',array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>40));
```

#### My User.php:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord { 
... 

public function rules(){        
  return array(
    array('username, password, email', 'required'),             
    array('created_by', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
    array('username, email', 'length', 'max'=>255),
    array('password', 'length', 'max'=>32),
    array('valid_from, valid_until, added_on', 'safe'),             
    array('username, email', 'unique'),
    array('id, type, username, password, email, valid_from, valid_until, 
    added_on,created_by','safe','on'=>'search'),
  );
...
}
```

#### My CustomUser.php

```
class CustomUser extends User
{
    public $password_verification;

    public function rules()
    {
        $newRules = array(
                array('password_verification', 'required'),
                array('password_verification', 'length', 'max' => 32),
                array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password_verification'),
                array('password_verification', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
        return array_merge(User::model()->rules(), $newRules);
    }
}
```

Do you think it's a problem with my `rules()` function? Do you have any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: have you declared any attribute label for `$password_verification` in customuser or user?

Comment: I declared that `public $password_verification;` in my CustomUser.php

Comment: in your form $user is of which type customuser or user?

Comment: I think you have to define password_verification in your model as public, then it can be accessed as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Define like this:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord { 

 $password_verification

 ....
```

Then your model would be able to access this attribute since you have defined this as a public property which will work as an attribute for Active Record.

Answer (score 0):

Error

> Property "User.password_verification" is not defined

says that you pass `User` model to your view, but `$password_verification` property exists only in `CustomUser` model.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

Finally it was a big mistake I did...-__-

I used in my view User instead of CustomUser (I was focus on actionCreate, I forgot actionIndex()...)

Sorry.

Have a good day

Michaël